# Getting an error when trying to use Microsoft LUIS and chat bot

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Recently we migrated our Microsoft LUIS from the email to the Azure portal. Everything worked fine until we migrated the portal. Now we are getting 401 (permission denied) errors.  We tried changing the keys and the endpoint but nothing has resolved the error? The other odd thing is that the chatbot is working when running locally through the emulator but fails when published. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling LUIS?

Comment: public virtual async Task<T> RecognizeAsync<T>(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            where T : IRecognizerConvert, new()
            => await _recognizer.RecognizeAsync<T>(turnContext, cancellationToken);

Comment: I am using the core bot from the bot framework v4. All of the recognizer stuff is the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that the keys on the blade in azure didn’t match the ones in the app settings.json. Once we made the keys match it works